# Absolute/Relative xPath selectors in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, xpath, webdriver-io

Quite a trivial question, but I haven't figured out yet how to split selectors into node elements to improve performances. I'm working on test automation for a Windows desktop application.

Let's take a random node :

```
const targetElement = await driver.$('//Window/Tab/TabItem/Custom/Pane/Group/Text');
const isDisplayed = await targetElement.isDisplayed();
assert.strictEqual(isDisplayed, true);
```

This above works like a charm.
But if I split the 'targetElement' into elements, it doesn't work anymore.

```
const pane = await driver.$('//Window/Tab/TabItem/Custom/Pane');
const targetElement = await pane.$('//Group/Text');
const isDisplayed = await targetElement.isDisplayed();
assert.strictEqual(isDisplayed, true);
```

will throw an error.

Comment: which error? also, xpath might need to be relative `.//Group/Text`

Comment: Basically, the element cannot be located, Hence the assert throws an inequality error because the element isn't found, isn't displayed.

Comment: .//Group/Text => That might be it . I'm new to Xpath and I understood so far that "//" was "current node" and have never read anything about relative .//

It's working so far, need further tests to confirm but thank you LMC

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative selection: `Group/Pane` instead of `//Group/Pane`. I have no idea whether that will help performance, I see no obvious reason why it should.

Comment: Well, I declared pane as a global variable and re-use it whenever i need to target an element within that pane.
It drasticallty improve performace rather than locate an element from the window app.

Comment: Goup/Text got me an error : 

✗ Error: invalid selector: The selector "Group/Text" used with strategy "css selector" is invalid!

So far I have seen no example of how enforce Xpath rather than css selector.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the webdriver-io API. It didn't occur to me that it might misinterpret an XPath expression as a CSS selector. Perhaps `./Group/Text` would work. A quick look at https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/ seems to suggest that only strings starting `//` are recognized as XPath expressions, but I might have got that wrong.